# WPF Text entrie field

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is it possible to have a Text Box (or something else) to enter user address with each entry on separate line?  And to set max number of lines to 3 lines (for Street, City, and State).
Please note, I am not looking for other solution but exactly to have some kind of text entry field taking these 3 on separate line like:

1234 Some Street
Some City
Some State

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest having 3 different text boxes, one for each item (Street, city, and state) but if it must be 1 box you can set AcceptsReturn to true and set your maxlines to 3 to make sure they only enter 1 address.

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="74,72,0,0" 
             TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" MaxLines="3" AcceptsReturn="True"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Yes it has to be one only. I also tried seting AcceptReturn to True and MaxLines to 3 but that does not limit number of lines in TextBox.  I think that just limits number of lines TextBox shows, however, user can still hit Enter and add line 4, 5, 6, ....

Answer (score 1):

You can explicit separate the text fields:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Name="addr1" KeyUp="Enter_KeyUp"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Name="addr2" KeyUp="Enter_KeyUp"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Name="addr3" KeyUp="Enter_KeyUp"></TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

And handle a pressing of Enter manually:

```
    private void Enter_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter) {
            var request = new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next);
            (sender as UIElement).MoveFocus(request);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry but it has to be one TextBox or something else.  Thanks for sharing ideas though.

Comment: You can join the text of three `TextBox`es very easy.

Answer (score 1):

Consider Casey Price's suggestion of using a multi line text box, and combine it with data validation.

See  http://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/08/26/data-validation-in-wpf/ which has an excellent outline of data validation.

Comment: Sorry but requirement is one TextBox or something else.

Comment: This approach will indeed use only one TextBox. You can write a converter that parses a multilingual text from a single TextBox, and apply validation to it. On the other hand, if your requirement is "one TextBox and no other code or xaml or other concepts", then it can't be done.